# Divide one table by another, with matching index

Tags: r

I have two table with a shared index, I want to divide one by another. This could be done with division on two data frames. But It seems arbitrary (how would I know I am dividing the right number?) and does not preserve index, so I want to do this division by matching rows with the same index. What's the best way to do this? Is there a best practice in terms of table division in this case?

```
tb1 <- data.frame(index = c(1, 2, 3), total_1 = c(100, 450, 300), total_2 = c(20, 39, 60))
tb2 <- data.frame(index = c(1, 2, 3), unit_1 = c(4, 2, 3), unit_2 = c(2, 3, 6))
tb1[,-1]/tb2[,-1]
  total_1 total_2
1      25      10
2     225      13
3     100      10
```

Another case, two col of index must match.

```
tb2 <- data.frame(index_1 = c("a", "b", "b"), index_2 = c("c", "d", "b"), unit_1 = c(4, 2, 3), unit_2 = c(2, 3, 6))
tb1 <- data.frame(index_1 = c("a", "b", "b"), index_2 = c("c", "d", "b"), total_1 = c(100, 450, 300), total_2 = c(20, 39, 60))
```

Comment: Do you have all index in both data

Comment: @akrun yes, both data has index, in the same order, but I want to make sure I explicitly enforce that

Comment: So you want to make sure the index rows always match? What about `tb1[,-1] / tb2[match(tb1$index,tb2$index), -1]`  ?

Comment: @thelatemail how would this work if I want to match two cols of index?

Comment: @KabochaPorter - you're starting to get in the territory of just doing a join/merge if you have multiple keys. I see akrun has already suggested this.

Answer (score 3):

If both data have the same index and the number of rows are same.  One way is to `order` by 'index' in both data to enforce that they are in the same order.  Then do the division

```
tb1new <- tb1[order(tb1$index),]
tbl2new <- tb2[order(tb2$index),]
tb1new[-1] <- tbl1new[-1]/tbl2new[-1]
```

---

Or we can make a check on both 'index' first and use that condition to do the division

```
i1 <- all.equal(tbl1$index, tbl2$index)
if(i1) tb1[-1]/tbl2[-1]
```

---

Or another option in a join

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('total_1', 'total_2')
nm2 <- c('unit_1', 'unit_2')
setDT(tb1)[tb2,  (nm1) :=  .SD/mget(nm2), on = .(index), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: is there a way to preserve the index as well? Does `order` work for categorical index?

Comment: @KabochaPorter it will be in alphabetic order.   Do you want to update the 'total' columns in 'tb1?

Comment: @KabochaPorter if you want to update the data by the divided values, just do an assignment with the same on the tb1

Comment: make sense, replacement isn't essential.

Comment: @KabochaPorter you can use a join as in the update if you have multiple columns to match i.e. specify `on = .(index_1, index_2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a join and divide the columns. In base R :

```
result <- merge(tb1, tb2, by = c('index_1', 'index_2'))
result

#  index_1 index_2 total_1 total_2 unit_1 unit_2
#1       a       c     100      20      4      2
#2       b       b     300      60      3      6
#3       b       d     450      39      2      3

total_cols <- grep('total', names(result), value = TRUE)
unit_cols <- grep('unit', names(result), value = TRUE)

result[total_cols]/result[unit_cols]

#  total_1 total_2
#1      25      10
#2     100      10
#3     225      13
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the most efficient solution but here is another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# For one index matching

tb1 %>%
  left_join(tb2, by = "index") %>%
  mutate(result_1 = get(paste("total", 1, sep = "_")) / get(paste("unit", 1, sep = "_")),
         result_2 = get(paste("total", 2, sep = "_")) / get(paste("unit", 2, sep = "_")))


  index result_1 result_2
1     1       25       10
2     2      225       13
3     3      100       10

# For two indices matching

tb1 %>%
  left_join(tb2, by = c("index_1", "index_2")) %>%
  mutate(result_1 = get(paste("total", 1, sep = "_")) / get(paste("unit", 1, sep = "_")),
         result_2 = get(paste("total", 2, sep = "_")) / get(paste("unit", 2, sep = "_"))) %>%
  select(!starts_with(c("total", "unit")))

  index_1 index_2 result_1 result_2
1       a       c       25       10
2       b       d      225       13
3       b       b      100       10
```